# Haskell - creating a function definition for the function `all` using foldr

Tags: haskell, predicate, fold

I'm trying to create a function definition for the function `all` using `foldr`. `p` is the predicate. I know this can be done:

```
all p = and . foldr (\x xs -> p x : xs) []
```

But what I want to do is to shift the function `and` into the `foldr` equation. Can this be done?

I've tried the following, which all failed to work:

```
all p = foldr (\x p -> \ys -> and (p x) ys) True
all p = foldr (\x and -> (\ys -> (p x and ys))) True
all p = foldr (\x ys -> and . (p x) ys) True
```

Am I falling short in my understanding of how to apply `foldr`?

Comment: It kinda looks like you're trying to _guess_ the correct version by randomly shuffling the words around. For example, what do you think `p x and ys` would mean?

Comment: Hint: `all p = and . map p` Note that `and` is outside the `map`.

Comment: @Fyodor: actually `and (p x) ys` is something I understand, which is equivalent to `(p x) && ys`.  I do not quite understand `p x and ys`.  It's not supposed to work unless I use backticks on `and`.  Somehow in foldr, I have to use `(&&)` and not simply `&&`.  This is something I do not understand too..

Comment: whether to use `&&` or `(&&)` is a matter of syntax, choosing what's appropriate in a given situation.

Comment: `and` works with lists, `(&&)` works with two arguments in the prefix position, or `&&` in infix.

Comment: could the dv'ers please explain their reasons?

Comment: @Joseph: I understand that `and` is outside `map`.  I'm trying to shift `and` into the `foldr` function for `map`.  That's how I got my first equation: `all p = and . foldr (\x xs -> p x : xs) []`

Comment: You can't use `and` inside the `foldr`, because it does the wrong thing. Replace `and` with its definition and then fuse that into your `foldr`.

Comment: @Will: Thanks, that's a good reminder, but I'm nowhere near a solution to my problem..

Comment: @Joseph: well, I've tried `all p = foldr (\x p -> \ys -> (&&) (p x) ys) True` before and it doesn't work.  In fact, I've tried both `and` and `(&&)`, and both don't work.. the error goes, Type: b -> (b -> Bool) -> Bool -> Bool, Does not match : a -> Bool -> Bool

Comment: That's because that's the wrong way to fuse them. The answer from Will Ness shows you the right way.

Comment: @Joseph: It is precisely all these type definitions that come out during errors that confuse me when I'm using `foldr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have

```
all p = and 
         . foldr (\x xs -> p x :  xs) []    
      = foldr                 (&&)   True   -- {y : ys} -> y && {ys}      2-3
         . foldr (\x xs -> p x :  xs) []    -- {x , xs} -> p x : {xs}   1-2
      =    foldr (\x xs -> p x && xs) True  -- {x , xs} -> p x && {xs}  1---3
```

because folding replaces each constructor with the specified combination operation (aka *reducer*), and replacing a *cons*  of an element with a *cons* of a modified element, and then replacing that *cons* with `(&&)`, is just replacing a *cons* of an element with the `(&&)` of a modified element right away:

```
    a  : (  b  : (  c  : (  d  : ( ... ))))   _OR_   []      --   |       |   1
                                                             --   |       |
  p a  : (p b  : (p c  : (p d  : ( ... ))))   _OR_   []      --   ↓   |   |   2
                                                             --       |   |
  p a && (p b && (p c && (p d && ( ... ))))   _OR_  True     --       ↓   ↓   3
```

In other words, folds compose by fusing their reducer functions, and reducer functions fuse by replacing the {constructors they use} with the next fold's reducer in the chain of folds, so that their corresponding *transducers* compose (as in Clojure's transducers); thus,

```
 = foldr              (reducingWith (&&)) True
     . foldr ((mapping p)    (:))           []
 = foldr ((mapping p) (reducingWith (&&))) True
 = foldr ((mapping p . reducingWith) (&&) ) True
   -- first map p, then reduce with (&&)
```

for the appropriate definitions of `reducingWith` and `mapping`:

```
reducingWith cons x xs = cons x xs
mapping f cons x xs = cons (f x) xs
filtering p cons x xs | p x = cons x xs
                      | otherwise = xs
concatting t cons x xs = foldr cons xs (t x)
```

Comment: Thanks!  But I still have questions because I have not learnt reducer functions.  How does foldr know that `xs` from `p x : xs` is a list if we replace the cons and the equation becomes `p x && xs`?  `&&` only applies to arguments right?

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand.  `Foldr` always works with lists, so the right associativity related to it is inbuilt.  There is no need to indicate a list by `x : xs`.  The cons can just simply be replaced.

Comment: I do not fully understand your explanation at `p a  : (p b  : (p c  : (p d  : ( ... ))))   -OR-   []       v    |    |`.  What do you mean by `v` and `|`?

Comment: that was my attempt as drawing vertical arrows using ASCII. those are supposed to be the  arrows going from the 1st row to the 2nd, and from the 2nd to the 3rd; and the composed arrows goes from the 1st row to the 3rd, corresponding to the fused fold. the `-OR-  X` means that it's `X` in case the list `[a,b,c,d,...]` was actually an empty list, `[]`.

Comment: Thanks!  You may be able to help with a new question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63547939/haskell-how-to-create-a-maptree-function-based-on-a-foldr-of-a-binarytree

Comment: @maxloo do consider *accepting* the most helpful answer to signal that your issue is resolved here. it *is* resolved, isn't it?

Comment: yes, I've just accepted your answer.  Thanks again!