# redefining the 'all' function in haskell

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions, fold

How can I redefine the `all` function in haskell using `foldr`?
I tried writing it like this and I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

```
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all p (x:xs) = foldr (&&) True ((p x) : (all p xs))
```

Comment: I think, the problem is that you're mixing `foldr` and recursion. It's enough to write `all p x = foldr (&&) True $ map p x`.

Comment: You should not call `all p xs`, `foldr` itself is a way to define recursion on a list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Haskell - creating a function definition for the function \`all\` using foldr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62851579/haskell-creating-a-function-definition-for-the-function-all-using-foldr)

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing the `foldr` and the function being defined with it. You're defining `all` with `foldr`, not with `all`. `foldr` captures the recursion pattern, it *replaces* the explicit recursion.

What you need is

```
all p xs  =  foldr (&&) True (map p xs)
          =  foldr ((&&) . p) True xs
```

because

```
all p [       x,             y       ]  = 
all p (       x :            y :  [] )  =
 =          p x &&        (p y && True )
 = ((&&) . p) x ( ((&&) . p) y    True )
```

because that's what `foldr g z xs` *is*: it replaces `:` in `xs` with `g`, and `[]` with `z`, turning e.g. `[x, y] = (x : y : [])` into `` x `g` (y `g` z) = g x (g y z) ``.

We also use

```
(f . g) x  =  f (g x)
```

by definition (`.` is called "function composition operator"), and

```
(&&) p q  =  p && q
```

because in Haskell, enclosing an infix operator in parentheses lets us treat is as a function.

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstand how `foldr` works. The idea is that, for a list, `foldr` replaces `(:)` with the folding function. This thus means that the second parameter of the fold function already is the result of folding the rest of the list.

This thus means that for:

```
all' :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool
all' p xs = foldr f True xs
    where f = …
```

`f` takes two parameters: an element of the list, and the `foldr f True` on the *rest* of the list. You thus can assume that the second parameter is already the `all'` function called on the rest of the list.

We thus can call `p` on the element `x`, and then calculate the logical and with the `all'` of the rest of the list, so:

```
all' :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool
all' p xs = foldr f True xs
    where f x as = p x && as
```

so here `x` is the head element of the list, and `as` is the `all'` called on the rest of the list.

We can rewrite `f x as = p x && as` to `f x = (p x &&)`, or even point-free with `f = (&&) . p`, so then we can rewrite `all'` to:

```
all' :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool
all' p = foldr ((&&) . p) True
```

or even make `all'` point-free with:

```
all' :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool
all' = flip foldr True . ((&&) .)
```